# Magento Attribute Options - Group same store value option with different admin value

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

in our admin we use the color option set as "dropdown"

we break down our colors very detail. For example in the "admin option values" we have

blue
blue lace
blue-green
blue-green

but on the front end "store view" we want the filter to just have 1 option "blue"

so in the "Manage Options (values of your attribute)" > "Default Store View" we put for all of those "blue"
[image: admin options]

but on our web site there ends up being 4 separate blue filters. 
[image: front end view]

is there a way on the front end to only see 1 option "blue" with all the products added up?
[image: what i want]

Answer (score 0):

### Exploratory solution:

You need do some custom coding in a class with a name something like the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter` , there should be a function there called `getItems()`.

The function itself just calls another function which creates a Zend query which grabs the information from the database.

You **should** explore until you find that Zend query builder and add a group by to the query.

Alternatively you **could** just take the array of items and modify it before returning it.

### Counter argument:

Removing the second, third etc. links from the getItems list should be fairly simple and you'll basically leave only the first link.

But when the user will click on the link the URL will be filtering by the first attribute the results of filtering by the second, third etc. attributes will not be shown.

You'll have to manipulate that logic as well.

### Counter proposal:

You can create an additional attribute such as "color_detail" which you can setup to not be visible in the front end or filterable or sortable etc. so none of the users can see it. BAM! Mission completed.

Another approach -- less intuitive -- if you're not already using and displaying product tags you could use those to tag the object with that particular color detail.

Another approach -- more intuitive especially if you want to keep track of stocks and/or allow the user to choose from the list of color details -- is using product options which can be configured to have their own SKU as well as their own stock inventory and can affect the product price and weight.